# SQL Server Upgrade 'Developer > Enterprise'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, licensing

My company purchased Visual Studio Pro 2008 last year, which had a 'free' copy of SQL Server Developer, which I have been using for development.

We are wanting to upgrade the copy of developer edition to enterprise (As we now want to use the server as a production server), and have purchased the licenses for this.

Now... Morally we're in the clear... However does this comply with MS licensing T&C's?

We have Developer installed how we want it, and don't really want to uninstall SQL Server Dev just to install SQL Server Ent. Is there a way to transfer the license key to our Enterprise key without having to reinstall?

Thanks,

JD

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade from Developer to Enterprise is a [supported upgrade path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143393.aspx), so you can simply install the new bits on top of the existing ones (provided your Developer is still at RTM and haven't patched any SP or CU on it).

Whether the license you purchased covers the use of the developer edition for business purposes, it is not explicitly called out in the [Licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/pricing-licensing-faq.aspx#licensing) document and I can't answer that part.

Comment: It's not quite that simple -- if you're upgrading the same version, select "Edition Upgrade" from the Maintenance menu in the installer.

The regular upgrade / install will tell you nothing to upgrade...

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx) is an msdn article that should help